# Azure Powershell how many times a service is called given a time range

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I can use Get-AzureRmResource and filter by resource type 
(Microsoft.Web/Sites) to have a list of web apps and services.
I need to get the answer to "Given this date range 1-1-2018 to present,
how many times each site has been called/used/visited?"

Do I use Get-AzureRmLog?  if no, what can I use?  If yes, what in log Analytics and give me the counts by service?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not really possible with these commands, they are related to the Azure platform

You need to use something like this:

```
Get-AzureRmAppServicePlanMetrics -ResourceGroupName "Default-Web-WestUS" -Name "ContosoWebApp" -StartTime 2016-11-30T22:00:00Z -EndTime 2016-11-30T22:30:00Z -Granularity PT1M -Metrics ["Requests"]
```

https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/60n0rl/azure_app_service_metrics/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/get-azurermwebappmetrics?view=azurermps-5.6.0